# npm start meteor fails at meteor npm i && meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, rocket.chat

I have been trying to set up development machine for Rocket.Chat on Ubuntu 16.04. Followed the steps given for prerequisite installations on the site and trying to execute npm start meteor. However the process fails at command  meteor npm i && meteor.

Below is the log of error that is 
[image: Log]

Any pointers on what is the possible issue. Pretty new to the framework and did not get any specific answer for my error on the forum.

Comment: What happens when you issue the `meteor` command?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I am getting error Failed to connect to server during installs . Below is the error : MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect. This is when I run meteor command.

Comment: Where? It is unclear what you have done and what the issue is. Please **edit your question** to provide more details regarding your exact actions and error messages. Take a look at the messages yourself and try to read any error logs they point to.

Comment: Somehow the mongo service was getting killed. Had to reinstall and problem was fixed. Anyway, I will try and rephrase the questions adding steps too.

Comment: @MasterAM There was some issue with the download. Was able to build and setup with source.

Comment: Do upgrade your node to latest version and see if it throws some other errors.

Comment: @a5his complete clean and reinstall did the trick. All working well now. There was issue with MongoDb installation.